# Reverse Loopback

Tags: linux, networking

How to configure reverse loopback on an ethernet device? In that case, all the traffic received will be sent back to transmitter connected to ethernet port.

Comment: Do you want to have the traffic actually leave the computer hardware and pass through a tp cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you could accomplish what you want using `iptables`. Looking through the [`iptables` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) I noticed this option called `tee`:

> TEE
>
> ```
>   The TEE target will clone a packet and redirect this clone to another
>   machine on the  local  network  segment.  In  other words, the nexthop 
>   must be the target, or you will have to configure the nexthop to forward
>   it further if so desired.
>
>   --gateway ipaddr
>
>          Send  the  cloned  packet  to the host reachable at the given IP 
>          address.  Use of 0.0.0.0 (for IPv4 packets) or :: (IPv6) is 
>          invalid.
>
>
>   To forward all incoming traffic on eth0 to an Network Layer logging box:
>
>   -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 2001:db8::1
> ```

It would seem that a command like this would do what you want:

```
$ iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway <ip address>
```

Also there is this tutorial titled: [Howto: Copy/Tee/Clone network traffic using iptables](http://www.bjou.de/blog/2008/05/howto-copyteeclone-network-traffic-using-iptables/), that covers how to use it in a little further details.

Comment: Hi Sir, This Options is nice in iptables, but can you tell why is it required ? any example , it would be better for me for understanding .. new things.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @RahulPatil - sure if you're familiar with the command line tool `tee` this is doing something similar with your network data where it's making a copy and sending it to the ip address you provide in the `--gateway` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two macvlan devices and bridging them to each other.